# How to add to zip csv file with generated files list

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, csv, zip

I have question about download file with php script and add it to zip.
I using now this script

```
<?php include "zahlavi.php"; ?>
<?php include_once('assets/bs4-paginator.class.php');  ?>
<?php include ('assets/config.php');  ?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"         
xmlns:addthis="https://www.addthis.com/help/api-spec"  prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" class="no-js">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>Generator</title>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://demo.learncodeweb.com/favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet"     
href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384- 
GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" 
 integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->

</head>
<body>

</div>




<div class="container">


    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading clearfix"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-globe"></i> 
    <strong>Prohlížení</strong>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h5><i class="fa fa-fw fa-search"></i>Hledat PM</h5>
                <form method="get">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Stav</label>
                                <input type="text" name="zak_stav" id="zak_stav" class="form-control" 
 value="<?php echo isset($_REQUEST['zak_stav'])?$_REQUEST['zak_stav']:''?>" placeholder="Zadat 
  stav...">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Datum ukončení el</label>
                                <input type="text" name="zak_termin_ukonceni_elektrina" id="zak_termin_ukonceni_elektrina" class="form-control" value="<?php echo isset($_REQUEST['zak_termin_ukonceni_elektrina'])?$_REQUEST['zak_termin_ukonceni_elektrina']:''?>" placeholder="Zadat termin ukončení..">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Datum ukončení pl</label>
                                <input type="text" class="tel form-control" name="zak_termin_ukonceni_plyn" id="zak_termin_ukonceni_plyn" x-autocompletetype="tel" placeholder="Zadat termín ukončení.." value="<?php echo isset($_REQUEST['zak_termin_ukonceni_plyn'])?$_REQUEST['zak_termin_ukonceni_plyn']:''?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>&nbsp;</label>
                                <div>
                                    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="search" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-search"></i> Hledat</button>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-sync"></i> Vyčistit filtr</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


            <hr>
            <div class="table table-responsive">
                <form method="post" action="createzip.php">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="bg-primary text-white">
                                <th width="25">id#</th>
                                <th>nazev pm</th>
                                <th>Jmeno</th>
                                <th>Prijmeni</th>
                                <th>Mesto</th>
                                <th>Ulice</th>
                                <th>Datum narozeni</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php
                            $condition  =   '';
                            if(isset($_REQUEST['zak_stav']) and $_REQUEST['zak_stav']!=""){
                            $condition  .=  ' AND zak_stav LIKE "%'.$_REQUEST['zak_stav'].'%" ';
                            }
                            if(isset($_REQUEST['zak_termin_ukonceni_elektrina']) and $_REQUEST['zak_termin_ukonceni_elektrina']!=""){
                            $condition  .=  ' AND zak_termin_ukonceni_elektrina LIKE "%'.$_REQUEST['zak_termin_ukonceni_elektrina'].'%" ';
                            }
                            if(isset($_REQUEST['zak_termin_ukonceni_plyn']) and $_REQUEST['zak_termin_ukonceni_plyn']!=""){
                            $condition  .=  ' AND zak_termin_ukonceni_plyn LIKE "%'.$_REQUEST['zak_termin_ukonceni_plyn'].'%" ';
                            }

                            $db         =   new mysqli('','','','');
                            mysqli_set_charset($db,"utf8");
                            $pages->default_ipp =   15;
                            $fileQry    =   $db->query("SELECT * FROM zakaznici WHERE 1 ".$condition." ORDER BY id_tabulky DESC LIMIT 30");

                            $pages->items_total =   count($fileQryql);
                            $pages->mid_range   =   9;
                            $pages->paginate(); 


                            if($fileQry->num_rows>0){
                                $s      =   '';
                                while($row  =   $fileQry->fetch_assoc()){
                                    $s++;
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $s;?></td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="fileId[]" class="custom-control-input" id="checkbox<?php echo $row['id_tabulky']?>" value="<?php echo $row['id_tabulky']?>">
                                        <label type="hiden" class="custom-control-label" for="checkbox<?php echo $row['id_tabulky']?>"><?php echo $row['zak_soubor_pm'];?></label>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                <?php echo $row['zak_jmeno'];?>
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                <?php echo $row['zak_prijmeni'];?>
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                <?php echo $row['zak_mesto'];?>
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                <?php echo $row['zak_ulice'];?>
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                <?php echo $row['zak_datum_narozeni'];?>
                                </td>


                            </tr>
                                <?php 
                                }
                            } ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2"><button type="submit" name="createzip" id="createzip" value="createzip" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-archive"></i> Stáhnout vybrané PM</button></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type="file"]').on('change', function () {
            let filenames = [];
            let files = document.getElementById('customFile').files;
            if(files.length>1){
                filenames.push('Total Files ('+files.length+')');
            }else{
                for (let i in files) {
                    if (files.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                        filenames.push(files[i].name);
                    }
                }
            }
            $(this).next('.custom-file-label').html(filenames.join(','));
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
<?php include "zapati.php"; ?>
```

For download files from database. Script works well

but I need add to this zip csv or excel file with file names with full path in rows with id of exported rows and more info from DB etc name of customer...

How I can do this ? How to add CSV export from this mysql table to this generated zip with files ?

Createzip.php contain is here:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_REQUEST['createzip']) and $_REQUEST['createzip']!=""){
extract($_REQUEST);

$filename   =   'temp/vygenerovane-pm.zip';

$db         =   new mysqli('','- 
 ','','');
mysqli_set_charset($db,"utf8");
$fileQry    =   $db->query('SELECT * FROM zakaznici WHERE id_tabulky IN 
  ('.implode(",",$fileId).')');

$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open($filename,  ZipArchive::CREATE)){
    while($row  =   $fileQry->fetch_assoc()){
        $zip->addFile(getcwd().'/'.'/'.$row['zak_soubor_pm'], 
 $row['zak_soubor_pm']);
    }


    $zip->close();

    header("Content-type: application/zip"); 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
    header("Content-length: " . filesize($filename));
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
    header("Expires: 0"); 
    readfile("$filename");
    unlink($filename);
}else{
   echo 'Failed!';
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Before download zip I create csv file and save it to temp after that link in to ZIP and after download files is been deleted in temp.